# In Hibernate,I am getting following error at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

In Hibernate,I am getting following error at runtime

**1. employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC

 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"

 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping package ="com.hibernate.basic">



    <class name="Employee" table="Employee" lazy="false">

        <id name="id" column="EMPID" type ="int">

            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="firstName" column="NAME"></property>
        <property name="lastName"column="LNAME"></property>

    </class>
```

**2. hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC

        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">



<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory> 
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.3.94:1521:EAMABP</property>
        <property name="connection.username">EAM</property>
        <property name="connection.password">EAM</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**3. Employee.java**

```
package com.hibernate.basic;

public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String FName, LName;

    public String getFName() {

        return FName;
    }

    public void setFName(String FName) {

        this.FName = FName;
    }

    public String getLName() {
        return LName;
    }

    public void setLName(String LName) {

        this.LName = LName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**4. StoreData.java**

```
package com.hibernate.basic;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class StoreData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creating configuration object
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");// populates the data of the
                                            // configuration file

        // creating seession factory object
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        // creating session object
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        // creating transaction object
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setId(115);
        e1.setFName("sonoo");
        e1.setLName("jaiswal");

        session.persist(e1);// persisting the object

        t.commit();// transaction is commited
        session.close();

        System.out.println("successfully saved");

    }
}
```

Error occurred after execution:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment). log4j:WARN Please initialize the
>   log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping
>   document from resource employee.hbm.xml   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:569)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
>     at com.hibernate.basic.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:13) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping
>   document from input stream    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:508)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:566)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 14
>   of document  : Element type "property" must be followed by either
>   attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". Nested exception: Element type
>   "property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or
>   "/>".     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)
>     ... 7 more

Answer (score 3):

There is a space missing between `name="lastName"` and `column`.

Comment: Thanks but in Java space at this property doesnt affect.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states the line number and the error.Having a look at this could help.

Error on line 14 of document : Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". Nested exception: Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: Sorry,but its not solving the problem..I am getting some other error

Comment: Thanks,but you are asking me to modify jar code which is not the exact issue..DOM parser is trying to parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs because your tags are not closed.Of what you have posted here,I guess you have not closed the hibernate-mapping tag in employee.hbm.Try doing that!
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sir,I have closed that tag previously.After fight of 3 days I learned three things please make note of it 1.If you define generator tag as increment then comment setID.2.In java class & mapping hibernate.hbm.xml  property name should be exactly same(This was my error). 3.Path of xml should be given very precisely in hibernate.cfg.xml..........

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

> Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>". Nested exception: Element type "property"
>   must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

And i fixed it changing a line in a *.hbm.xml file

There was a space missing between column="ESAMBIGUA" and length="1"/>

The first comment, the one from *Eduard Wirch* really helped me. Thanks!